# my data did not insert into databse while other tables is working

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert

I have face an issue when I insert the data into the database through PHP in the missing_mans table it did not insert while when I change the table name to something else it inserted.
Below are the code and the database table.

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include'includes/connection.php';
if(isset($_GET['type'])){
$type=  $_GET['type'];
switch ($type) {


    case 'missingperson':
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $fname=$_POST['name'];

            $query=$conn->query("insert into missing_mans(name) values('$fname')");
            if ($query) {
                echo "Sucess";
            }
            else{
                    
                echo "issue";
            }
        

    }
    break;
```

this is my database table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZVEm.png)

Comment: A lot of database columns are marked as `NOT NULL` and don't have any default value, which will cause an error and will not let you insert record. Either allow null in other columns or pass values for each column.

Comment: if you wanna use NULL value, you need validate $fname=$_POST['name']; and use values('" .$fname."')..  Suggestion: make better validation, your system can be vunarable.

Comment: @user1149440 how to validate what does it mean to validate

Comment: `echo "issue"` is useless balast, use php mysqli error handlers www.php.net/manual/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use one the following ways:

---

put this query instead of your query:

```
$query = $conn->query("INSERT INTO `missing_mans` (`id`, `name`, `father_name`, `age`, `color`, `height`, `gender`, `description`, `picture`, `address`, `user_id`, `district_id`, `missing_data`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $fname . "', '', 0, '', 0, '', '', '', '', 0, 0, CURRENT_DATE(), 0)");
```

---

execute this queries in your database and run your own php code again:

```
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `name`            VARCHAR    (25)   NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `father_name`     VARCHAR    (25)   NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `age`             INT        (20)   NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `color`           VARCHAR    (20)   NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `height`          INT        (20)   NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `gender`          VARCHAR    (30)   NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `description`     TEXT              NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `picture`         VARCHAR    (30)   NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `address`         TEXT              NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `user_id`         INT        (30)   NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `district_id`     INT        (2)    NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `missing_data`    DATE              NULL;
ALTER TABLE   `missing_mans`   MODIFY   `status`          TINYINT    (1)    NULL;
```

Comment: $query = "select missing.id as id, missing.name as name,missing.father_name as father_name, missing.age as age, missing.missing_date as missing_date, missing.picture as picture, district.district_name as dname, user.name as uname from missing inner join district on missing.district_id = district.id inner join user on missing.user_id = user.id";   when I put the where class in the last it is not working please tell me how can I do this?